# Check if all bits in BitSet are set to true

Tags: java, bitset

I'm using a `BitSet` in my application and would like to check with a method if all used bits in the `BitSet` are set to `true`. Now, I know of the method `isEmpty()` that checks if all bits are set to `false`, however I can't seem to find the positive case. I'm aware I could do something like `someBitSet.cardinality() == someBitSet.size()`, but this seems clumsy. Am I missing something or is there an explicit reason why such a method is not implemented but the opposite case is?

Answer (score 9):

There's no thing like "all bits in `BitSet`", because at any time you can set the bit which is greater than the maximal bit set so far. Suppose that you want to keep in `BitSet` up to 10 values. So you set 10 bits and want to check whether all of them are true. However `BitSet` does not know that you have only 10 bits. What if you have more? Next time you can call `bitSet.set(10000)` and it will work (`BitSet` will resize automatically).

Note that `bitSet.size()` is not very helpful in general case: it's about consumed memory. Current implementation is always a multiple of 64, so if you have only 10 different states, `someBitSet.cardinality() == someBitSet.size()` will always return false. Even if you created the `BitSet` with `new BitSet(10)`. The constructor parameter is just a desired initial capacity (like in `ArrayList`). It's used as performance hint only.

The best solution from the performance point of view is to check `nextClearBit(0) >= myLength` where `myLength` is the maximal number of values you want to store in `BitSet` (you should keep it by yourself). This may work faster than `cardinality()` if the result is `false`.

Comment: Yes, however the documentation says that:_a bit set has a current size, which is the number of bits of space currently in use by the bit set._ That's why I figured that it would be useful if one could easily check whether all of them were set to true. EDIT: Ok, saw your edit just now. Thanks. Then I suppose a bit set might not be my data structure of choice here.

Comment: @Jonathan, it will work if you actually need 64, 128, 192 etc. bits. Any other initial size will be automatically extended to the next multiple of 64 (and it's implementation detail, you cannot rely on it!).

Comment: It seems you are missing [`BitSet.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length--): “*Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one*” which is exactly the desired thing, in contrast to `size()`. So the operation you want is `bs.length()==bs.nextClearBit(0)` which works and is potentially more efficient than a `cardinality()` based solution, but is still as clumsy.

Comment: One can use either: `bitSet.nextClearBit(0)==bitSet.length()` or  `bitSet.cardinality()==bitSet.length()`. Where  nextClearBit(0) may be efficient than a cardinality() on very big bit set; Considering bitset with some ten/hundred of thousands of elements, I could not measure any difference in speed.